# using sql to get one random record(row) from each group in database

Tags: sql-server, filter, group-by, common-table-expression

I want to get one random library card from each group, group are column "state"

```
    select library card, state
    from [stategov]..library 
    where states in (
    'Ohio',
    'Arizon'
    )
group by state, librarycard
```

Should I use top 1? or CTE?

Since each state can have more than 10,000 library cards. What is the best way to get one random library cards from each state using group by?

Comment: Why are you using `with (nolock)`? You want unpredictable results?

Comment: @dale k sorry I meant by group by using states. ANd yes nolock is  bad habit

Comment: The duplicate gives you a random row per group by as requested. However you would benefit from improving your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like following using `ROW_NUMBER()`. To get random you need to order by `newid()`

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STATE ORDER BY (SELECT newid())) rn
    FROM [stategov]..library WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE states IN (
            'Ohio'
            ,'Arizon'
            )
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```